# Conditionally importing a JS module based on imported module's properties

Tags: javascript, webpack, dynamic-import

This question relates to a JS app, bundled by Webpack

I'm trying to get my head around a pattern for conditionally importing a module. The condition for the import would be dependant on a static property of an imported class.

Given I have have this class Foo:

```
// Foo.js

export class Foo {
 static condition = 'bar';
}
```

I would like to perform a conditional import like this:

```
if (Foo.condition === 'bar') {
 const { Foo } = await import('Foo.js');
}
```

How could I get this reference to Foo.condition without first importing the class, and negating the benefit of using a dynamic import later?

Comment: No, you can't. You either import it or not.

Comment: Your condition should not depend on imported module to not import it

Comment: Nothing I can do at build time to allow it to be conditional at runtime?

Comment: The Foo module has to be loaded, parsed, and evaluated for the state of `condition` to be known.

Comment: but it was working using require... import seems like an unfinished thing compared to python...